# monitoring Amazon EC2 instances without cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, monitoring

I would like to monitor the following on Amazon ec2 instances loaded with amazon linux, every X minutes :

disk statistics
process stats (similar to what `top` does)
ram usage
check if my scripts are running fine

should I use my own scripts and things or are there any tools that already achieve this ?
I searched and there was a suggestion about [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)

what seems to be the better approach ?

Comment: can any of the mentioned softwares give me number of open handles in linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use zabbix with mikoomi will get all result the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it with Munin.. It's easy.  Just allow port 4949 through the firewall/Security Group to your munin server, and everything just works. (Remember to add the munin server to munin-node.conf on the EC2 node)

Comment: seems good to me too... was searching if there was anything better :)

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why you do not want to use Cloudwatch?

It has a free level (15 monitoring interval).

Comment: It doesn't give process statistics like,
how much memory a particular process is using, 
is the system running absolutely fine,
is my application stack i.e scripts and other services are running fine,
etc.. 
And then, I guess we can do better by running our own scripts or third party tools like munin or nagios.